# Redirect using Node.js after correct or incorrect results

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, handlebars.js

I’m new to web development.
Have a simple Node.js app running express and using handlebars: index.hbs, results.hbs.

index.hbs (simplified)

```
<div id="answer">
   The answer:<span>answer="{{answer}}"></span>
</div>
```

results.hbs (simplified)

```
<div id="results">
   You are {{result}}! The answer is:<span>answer="{{answer}}"></span>
</div>
```

server.js

```
 app.get('/results', async function(req, res) {
   const answer = req.body.answer;

   res.render('results', {
      answer: answer
  });
});
```

client.js

```
  function displayResults() {
    var results = number1 + number2;
    var result;

    if (results == correctAnswer) {
        result = "correct";
        answer = results;
    } else {
        result = "incorrect";
        answer = number1 + number2;
    }

    fetch('/results', {
      method: 'POST',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(result, answer) //how to send the result, answer to results.hbs?
    }).then(function (res) {
      // redirect to new page?
    }).catch(function (e) {
      console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
    });
  }
```

I have a client JavaScript that asks the sum of two numbers.

Once the answer is retrieved it determines if the answer is correct. If it is it sends the results as "correct", otherwise "incorrect" and the answer.

I’ve tried using POST via the fetch method on app.post(‘/results’)… and app.get(‘/results’)… but I’m confused on which to use to pass the value to display the result and answer and redirect to the results.hbs.

Questions:

1. How do I get the value from the client JavaScript to the Node.js server and pass it to '/results.hbs? Do I use a POST or GET?
2. How do I redirect to the “results.hbs” page from the Node.js server?

Thanks for the help. I know these are pretty basic but I’m not finding the answers specific to my use case.

Comment: I find it difficult to understand what you are asking. I think there is some confusion over what the different pieces of the system do. For example, Handlebars files are templates, not pages - so I don't understand the, "...to pass the value to the “correct.hbs” page" part of your question.

Comment: Please read this [https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I’ve updated the questions with code.

Comment: Handlebars is best suited for a server-side rendered web application. You don't need the client-side JavaScript for what you're trying to do. Look into handling a form submit using Express and handlebars.

Comment: Thx @NeonD for the suggestion. Sadly I have a need for this architecture defined so I do need to push the data from the client to the server and pass it back down to another page.